# Implementing a readonly version of an application

Tags: java, web-applications, readonly

Given an java web application that is currently running in a server, will deploying the same app (giving it a new context name ie. /app-readonly) but provide it with a readonly db account the only thing I need to make a readonly version of a web application.

I would expect that this readonly version of the application will be able to view, search but any updates/creates that are triggerred from the screen will just return an error (which is fine). This is the simplest solution I can think of, without introducing a code change in order to give finer grain control on the application's user access control. At the moment the user access control only dictates what screens are accessible to a user. It is not complex in that it does not dictate what the user can do in a given accessible page.

Is this a correct approach or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

That approach is good only if you specifically want to deploy a new web application.

In my view you should create read only user and give that user access limited to Search, view.

In this case user wont have the rights to perform insert, update.

This approach should be there within your project, who can access what ? If you have to deploy a new app for view only, IMHO you need to revisit your access control design.

Comment: yes, this approach will not touch the access control of the app, as at the moment this access control only dictates what screens are accessible to user (it does not have finer grain control such as what it can do on that accessible screen). the quickest and simplest solution is to leave the access control as is and just deploy a readonly version of the app where the user can login using the same access control; no code changes are introduced and it can be delivered in tight schedule

Comment: But in order to throw exception on insert update, you will do some code changes, Right ? If you cannot change the design then your approach seems to be the only resolution.

Comment: the app already catches any db error and translates to a generic db error when it gets back to the screen.